# PHP Foreach loop take an additional step forward from within the loop

Tags: php, foreach

Basically I have a foreach loop in PHP and I want to:

```
foreach( $x as $y => $z )  
    // Do some stuff  
    // Get the next values of y,z in the loop  
    // Do some more stuff
```

Comment: Can you provide a "real" example of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 7):

It's not practical to do in a `foreach`.

For **non-associative arrays**, use `for`:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < count($y); $x++)
 {
   echo $y[$x];  // The current element

   if (array_key_exists($x+1, $y))
    echo $y[$x+1]; // The next element

   if (array_key_exists($x+2, $y))
    echo $y[$x+2]; // The element after next

 }
```

For **associative arrays**, it's a bit more tricky. This should work:

```
$keys = array_keys($y); // Get all the keys of $y as an array

for ($x = 0; $x < count($keys); $x++)
 {
   echo $y[$keys[$x]];  // The current element

   if (array_key_exists($x+1, $keys))
    echo $y[$keys[$x+1]]; // The next element

   if (array_key_exists($x+2, $keys))
    echo $y[$keys[$x+2]]; // The element after next

 }
```

When accessing one of the next elements, make sure though that they exist!

Comment: You should probably add some test here, to check that `$x+1` is not bigger than `count($y)`

Comment: You'll get errors here for 2 reasons...  1) <= should probably be <, and 2) if you're on the last element of the array, $y[$x+1] won't exist.  See my answer below.

Comment: @Pascal true, that's probably faster than doing an `array_key_exists()`

Comment: I would also go with this. You just need a check to make sure that you are not running out of index the last two loops.

Comment: @jweber the `array_key_exists()` call should handle that.

Comment: Also, your array $x needs to be non-associative. We don't know what $x in the example is, it could be a key-value map.

Comment: @kander I added an approach that deals with associative arrays.

Comment: Nice! I created my own variation of that before I noticed you had updated your answer :) Slightly more verbose than yours, though.

Answer (score 1):

use the `continue` keyword to skip the rest of this loop and jump back to the start.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you simply want to do just "some stuff" with the first element, only "some more stuff" with the last element, and both "some stuff" and "some more stuff" with every other element. Or if you want to do "some stuff" with the first, third, fifth elements, and "some more stuff" with the second, fouth, sixth elements, etc.

```
$i = 0;
foreach( $x as $y => $z )   
    if (($i % 2) == 0) {
       // Do some stuff   
   } else {
       // Do some more stuff 
   }
   $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, following up on my comment on Pekka's solution, here is one that takes into account the fact that the array might be associative. It's not pretty, but it works. Suggestions on how to improve this are welcomed!

```
<?php
    $y = array(
        '1'=>'Hello ',
        '3'=>'World ',
        '5'=>'Break? ',
        '9'=>'Yup. '
    );

    $keys = array_keys($y);
    $count = count($y);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        // Current element    
        $index = $keys[$i];
        echo "Current: ".$y[$index];  // The current element

        if (array_key_exists($i+1, $keys)) {
            $index2 = $keys[$i+1];
            echo "Next: ".$y[$index2]; // The next element
        }

       if (array_key_exists($i+2, $keys)) {
            $index3 = $keys[$i+2];
            echo "Nextnext: ".$y[$index3]; // The element after next
        }
     }
?>
```

Comment: Heh, we had the same idea at the same time. +1 for verbosity.

Answer (score 0):

try something like...

```
for ($i=0, $i<count($x); $i++)
{
    // do stuff with $x[$i]
    // do stuff with $x[$i+1], unless you're on the last element of the array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
reset($arr);
while(list($firstindex,$firstvalue) = each($arr)){
   list($secondindex,$secondvalue) = each($arr);
   //do something with first & second.
}
```